# [SQL Server]Invalid column name

Tags: php, sql-server, database

I'm doing a search query into my MS SQL database, and I cannot figure out why I am getting this error. It is saying that there is no column name for what I am searching for, which isn't making sense to me because it should be searching within the specified column for my search. This is the error I'm getting:

> Booklist Query Failed, Error: Array ( [0] => Array ( [0] => 42S22
>   [SQLSTATE] => 42S22 [1] => 207 [code] => 207 [2] => [Microsoft][ODBC
>   Driver 13 for SQL Server][SQL Server]Invalid column name 'Hello'.
>   [message] => [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 13 for SQL Server][SQL
>   Server]Invalid column name 'Hello'. ) )

And this is my code where I'm having the issues:

```
function htmlBookList($search) {
    $connection = new Connection(); 
    $conn = $connection->connect(); 
    $query = ""; 

    if($search == "") {
        $query = "SELECT * FROM libraryData";
    } else {
        $query = "SELECT * FROM libraryData WHERE Title LIKE $search"; 
    }

    $bookList = sqlsrv_query($conn, $query);

    echo "<table border=1 cellpadding=1 cellspacing=1>
                <tr>
                    <th> Title </th>
                    <th> Author </th>
                    <th> Genre </th>
                    <th> Copies </th>
                </tr>";

    if (!$bookList) {
          print("Booklist Query Failed, Error: \n");
          print_r(sqlsrv_errors());
      } else {
        while($row = sqlsrv_fetch_array($bookList)) {
                echo "<tr>";
                echo "<td>" . $row['Title'] . "</td>";
                echo "<td>" . $row['Author'] . "</td>";
                echo "<td>" . $row['Genre'] . "</td>";
                echo "<td>" . $row['Copies'] . "</td>";
                echo "</tr>";
            }
            echo "</table>"; 
      }
}
```

- The database name is correct and exists.
- I have a book in my database table for testing with the title "Hello".
- I have a column name that is "Title".
- If I do an empty search, it shows everything in my database like it's supposed to with no problems.
- I've looked at the syntax of a search query in a few different sources and it seems to be exactly the same.
- I've refreshed and hard refreshed my webpage multiple times.
- My database table is named "libraryData" with ID, Title, Author, Genre, and Copies as columns.
- If I change the search text to "Title", it '*works*' and show's me everything in the database that has a Title.
- If I scrap the $search variable and do a plain string, it gives me the same error.

I'm not understanding why it thinks that the $search is supposed to be a column name, when it should be what it's searching for within the column.  Could someone please help me understand why it's doing this? Is this a server problem or is there something I'm missing? Thanks for your time in advance.

Comment: Use parameterised queries. Your current approach is open to SQL injection.

Comment: The problem is the missing single quotes around the search term.  As Martin suggests, the solution is parameterized queries.

Comment: As suggested, wrap the $search in single quotes.

Comment: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/brian_swan/2010/03/04/whats-the-right-way-to-prevent-sql-injection-in-php-scripts/

Comment: That did it...could've sworn I tried that already along with 10 other options. Thank you!

Comment: What did it? Single quotes? Don't do that. It is not secure. The link above shows how to parameterise it.

Comment: The single quotes did work, but I read up on your link and changed it. Learning PHP and that was a great help, thank you!